# SSIS SQL task stopped working after upgrading to 2012 from 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, collation, sql-server-data-tools

I´m looking for any information what could cause a package (that is working on multiple 2008 r2 environments) stop working when upgraded to 2012.

All the SQL-tasks have started to malfunction and I do not know why.
Here is an example .

I get a collation error, even though I recreated the database to be in right collation and remade the query, so it does not join any more.

How is it possible to get a collation error without join!

```
use master
DECLARE @db varchar(100)
DECLARE @tid varchar(3)
DECLARE @queryta varchar(max)
SET @db= ?
SET @tid = ?
SET @queryta='

  SELECT smt.nro  COLLATE database_default as  yr, 
  smt.type  COLLATE database_default AS tyyppi,
  ISNULL(CAST(CONVERT(date,smt.dt1) AS VARCHAR),''1799-12-30'')  COLLATE database_default AS dt,
  ISNULL(CAST(CONVERT(date,smt.dt12 AS VARCHAR),''1799-12-30'') COLLATE database_default AS dt2
  FROM [mydatabase].[dbo].[table] as smt
WHERE  smt.T_Id='''+@tid+'''
'
exec(@queryta)
```

The error:

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "use master DECLARE @db
> varchar(100) DECLARE @..." failed with the following error: "Implicit
> conversion of varchar value to varchar cannot be performed because the
> collation of the value is unresolved due to a collation conflict
> between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS" in
> add operator.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query,
> "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly,
> or connection not established correctly.

I am using SQL Server Data Tools to debug. What can I try next?

### Edit

I have enforced collation, but there was no change.

Comment: I think that when the data tools still remember the first database I created, even though I have deleted it and recreated it.

Comment: I think the problem Is the instance collation (hence `master` and `msdb`), not the DB collation. Your previous instance was `Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS` and the new one is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` ? You need to explicitly force the desired collation.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Do you mean using COLLATE database_default, it does not help

Comment: BTW the query has always worked on management studio. This error comes up only in sql-task on SSIS

Answer (score 0):

@RemusRusanu Is right. The server collation is Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS and the database collations are Latin something. The error is a bug in SSIS behavior as the query is valid and runs in the management studio.

I can not use **use master** command and 3 part naming to access the right database, the one with different collation. No amount of casting or enforcing collation seems to fix it (the server should have been set up with Latin something collation as all the DB´s seem to use it).

The solution was simply to change **use master** -> **use mydatabase**

Thanks for @RemusRusanu